# MySQL indexing compared to SQL Server

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, database, indexing

Does MySQL have a **`sysindexes`** table or am I just thinking of SQL Server? If not, is there an equivalent indexing feature within MySQL at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB tables can definitely be indexed; not sure about the scope available with ISAM tables. The system information stuff is held in the information schema tables:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/schemata-table.html

Answer (score 2):

SYS tables are specifically SQL Server; the ANSI equivalent is `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.  Part of the reason SYS tables still exist on SQL Server is they sometimes include additional information not in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables...

On [MySQL, you want to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/statistics-table.html):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
 WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
   AND table_schema = 'db_name'
```